# Control connectivity of resistors in voltage divider arrangement

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, pic, switches, voltage-divider

[image]

I am building a device to measure the resistance of a resistor using a voltage divider.  I added multiple resistors so that the range of the divider could be changed by switching to another resistor.  However, only one resistor should ever be connected to ground at the same time.  I was wondering what the best way to control which resistors are connected to ground is.  I thought about using a transistor to control it, but I though that the added resistance and voltage drop could potentially cause issues.  The device runs on a pic18f2550.  What would be the best way to control the connections of the resistors from the PIC?

Comment: What range of resistance do you want your circuit to be able to measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an N-channel MOSFET with low \$R_{DS-ON}\$ at \$V_{GS}=5V\$ on each ground connection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffGF0D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, you will want to buffer the signal through a voltage follower with a very high input impedance since the 1MΩ resistance range will give incorrect results due to it being too high an impedance for the ADC to reliably measure.  The maximum recommended impedance for an ADC is usually in the 5kΩ - 10kΩ range.  In fact, inspecting the datasheet, you can see:

> ## 21.1 A/D Acquisition Requirements
>
> ...
>   The maximum recommended impedance for analog sources is 2.5 kΩ.
>   ...

Comment: Is there a mosfet you recommend?

Comment: There's plenty to choose from. I can't come up with any part numbers off the top of my head, but a parametric search of your favourite supplier will throw up hundreds of options.

Comment: Would this Mosfet https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/RF/RFP12N10L.pdf work?